# How to view video from a VC500 Capture Device via gstreamer-java in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, gstreamer

I'm trying to build a pipeline with gst-launch in Windows 7 that will view a stream from a VC500 Video Capture device (Captures composite video and inputs to computer via USB). I think my biggest issue here is the fact that it MUST be done in Windows. I'm finding a lot of the plugins for gstreamer-java are supported in Linux instead of Windows. So I'm having issues finding the element and syntax to get this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Another thing is I don't have to use the gstreamer framework for this, it just seems to be the easiest. If anyone knows another good media framework with good Java bindings that might be better let me know? Haha. (Tried DirectShow, VLCJ, neither are very stable for Java.)
Thanks a lot.
Brayden

EDIT:
From more reading I'm pretty sure the element I need here is ksvideosrc.

So I've been trying: 
`gst-launch -v ksvideosrc ! autovideosink`

But I get:

> ERROR: from element
>   /GSTPipeline:pipeline0/GstKsVideoSrc:ksvideosrc0:
>   could not start capture Additional
>   debug info:
>   ..........\Source\gst-plugins-bad\sys\winks\gstvideosrc.c(970):
>   gst_ks_video_src_create ():
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstKsVideoSrc:ksvideosrc0:failed
>   to change pin state to KSSTATE_RUN
>   Execution ended after 1000000 ns.

Comment: Any help at all? Anyone? :/ I'm not making much progress here..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright well.. I ended up using Direct Show Java (dsj) instead. It was able to play video from the capture device very easily.